# Clojure & Overtone: Jackd not launching

Tags: clojure, jack, overtone

I'm trying to use Overtone but when I launch it, I get an error about jackd.

```
bambalaam@bambalaam:~/Desktop/clojuretest$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 59002
user=> (use 'overtone.live)
--> Loading Overtone...
--> Booting internal SuperCollider server...
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/home/bambalaam/Desktop/clojuretest/native/linux/x86_64/libscsynth.so: undefined symbol: load'
Found 0 LADSPA plugins
*** ERROR: open directory failed '/home/bambalaam/.local/share/SuperCollider/synthdefs'
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
audio_reservation_init
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
JackTemporaryException : now quits...
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Failed to open server
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f106433f0dc, pid=12155, tid=139707466204928
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_85-b01) (build 1.7.0_85-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.85-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.1
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libscsynth.so+0x220dc]  SC_UdpInPort::SC_UdpInPort(World*, int)+0x9c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/bambalaam/Desktop/clojuretest/hs_err_pid12155.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
could not initialize audio.
bambalaam@bambalaam:~/Desktop/clojuretest$
```

It is an almost fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 where I installed leiningen and tried to install what is suggested here: https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki/Installing-and-starting-jack

The jackd command they suggest to run doesn't work either and gives errors too.

Comment: Have you also installed SuperCollider IDE? There is an Error about not being able to find the directory SuperCollider.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your jack configurations are not set right with your audio card. Try downloading QJackCtl (a GUI for jackd) and start jack before lunching Overtone. If you successfully start jack with QJackCtl then overtone should start properly. In Ubuntu you should be able to find it with apt-get install qjack*

Note that you might want to choose playback only if you're not sure how to configure line-in (ex. microphone).